How to create new event handler with custom name in easy way in WPF?
I've been wondering what's the shortcut or other way to create new event handler for an element in XAML,when I type Click="" VS shows me an option to create new event handler with generic name but when I select it by myself,then it does not show it even when I click on it and select option "show code".
I've been trying to find an answer online

It's not clear what you are doing or what issue you've encountered, but ensure that you have given the element a name before subscribing to an event.

I assume you want to create a custom event for UI control. Here is a sample:
Create a custom event called PartialTextSelected for a TextBox control in WPF, you can follow these steps:

Create a custom TextBox control: Derive a class from TextBox.
Add the custom event: Define a custom routed event.
Override necessary methods: Override the OnSelectionChanged method to raise the custom event when partial text is selected.

Define the custom TextBox control:
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomControls
{
    public class PartialTextBox : TextBox
    {
        // Define the routed event
        public static readonly RoutedEvent PartialTextSelectedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "PartialTextSelected", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(PartialTextBox));

        // Provide CLR accessors for the event
        public event RoutedEventHandler PartialTextSelected
        {
            add { AddHandler(PartialTextSelectedEvent, value); }
            remove { RemoveHandler(PartialTextSelectedEvent, value); }
        }

        // Override OnSelectionChanged to raise the event when partial text is selected
        protected override void OnSelectionChanged(RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

            if (SelectionLength > 0 && SelectionLength < Text.Length)
            {
                RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(PartialTextSelectedEvent));
            }
        }
    }
}

Use the custom TextBox control in XAML:
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:PartialTextBox Width="200" Height="30" PartialTextSelected="PartialTextBox_PartialTextSelected"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Handle the custom event in the code-behind:
using System.Windows;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PartialTextBox_PartialTextSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Partial text selected!");
        }
    }
}

